# How to get PKEY_Device_FriendlyName if it's not defined

Tags: c++

I want to enumerate all available AudioDevices from Audio Endpoints, using IPropertyStore.
But VC++ linker can't find reference to PKEY_Device_FriendlyName operand in header and lib files.

I need a quick solution, what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add to your code:

```
    static PROPERTYKEY key;

    GUID IDevice_FriendlyName = { 0xa45c254e, 0xdf1c, 0x4efd, { 0x80, 0x20, 0x67, 0xd1, 0x46, 0xa8, 0x50, 0xe0 } };
    key.pid = 14;
    key.fmtid = IDevice_FriendlyName;
    PROPVARIANT varName;
    // Initialize container for property value.
    PropVariantInit(&varName);
```

and pass &key into IPropertyStore* ->GetValue(key, &varName);

Comment: Is there an explanation about this?